# How to make sort arrows in angular mat-table always visible?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7

The goal is to make sorting arrows of angular mat-table always visible (e.g. they have always opacity set to 0.54).

I tried adding some css code to my `.css` file for this component. It made all arrows visible (I set opacity to 0.54), but in this case all arrows stay with this opacity always, even if an arrow was clicked (normally the opacity will set to 1 if the arrow was clicked).

The code I added to my `.css` file:

```css
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-arrowPosition {
  opacity: 0.54 !important;
}
```

I want that arrows are always displayed with the Opacity 0.54. The rest behavior of the arrows should remain unchanged. In the case where a column is unsorted, e.g., the arrow is in an undefined state, the arrow should be an up arrow and have the opacity 0.54. If I click on the arrow, it should have the opacity set to 1. If I cancel the sorting, the arrow should have the opacity 0.54 again.

There is an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isxoc5. All arrows are displayed as I want. But if you click an arrow, it still have the opacity 0.54, not 1.

Comment: Hi @Albert .mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted) .mat-sort-header-arrow {opacity: 0.54 !important; transform: translateY(0px) !important; } this should do the job :)

Comment: Hi @ErvinLlojku . Thanks, youur solution does exactly what I want. 
Could you maybe advise me something else? If I click on the arrow twice (and thus cancel the sorting), the arrow is an down arrow. If this arrow loses the focus and then gets the focus again, the arrow is an up arrow, not down arrow more. Can I somehow automate this behavior so the arrow will automatically refresh and immediately became an up arrow after the sorting is canceled?

Comment: Hi @Albert .mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted) .mat-sort-header-indicator {transform: translateY(0px) !important; } .mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted) .mat-sort-header-pointer-left {transform: rotate(-45deg) !important; } .mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted) .mat-sort-header-pointer-right {transform: rotate(45deg) !important; } try this. I personally try to avoid !important because impacts performance. The other solution would be to create a custom directive to handle sorting :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just as Ervin commented but using ng-deep

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container:not(.mat-sort-header-sorted) .mat-sort-header-arrow {
  opacity: 0.54 !important;
  transform: translateY(0px) !important;
}
```

This doesn't remove the animations on the arrows on hover enter and hover exit though.

Comment: Yep, thanks, it works. I added ::ng-deep myself.
Could you maybe advise me something else? If I click on the arrow twice (and thus cancel the sorting), the arrow is an down arrow. If this arrow loses the focus and then gets the focus again, the arrow is an up arrow, not down arrow more. Can I somehow automate this behavior so the arrow will automatically refresh and immediately became an up arrow after the sorting is canceled?

Comment: @AlbertSteiner Sorry but I don't know how to fix that as it is an animation and from what I understand, you need to attach to and modify the animation in runtime. You should mark this as answer and open a new question for help on angular animations.

Comment: @AlbertSteiner Did you get an answer to your original question? If so you should mark that solution as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In mat-table insert [@.disabled]

```
<mat-table [@.disabled]="true">
```

Add this in scss

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-arrow {
    transform: none !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An arrow when click applies a sorting to it, it can either be a ascending sort or a descending sort - no such thing as sort being cancelled... No matter how many times we click on a column heading, some (asc or dsc) sorting will be applied and hence we should see the arrow with `opacity: 1`. To do this, we keep track of each click and apply the `boldArrow` class to `th`. Styling for `opacity:1` is done when in reference to this class

relevant **TS**:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'table-sorting-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-sorting-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-sorting-example.html',
})
export class TableSortingExample implements OnInit {
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
  sortedStatus: boolean[] = [];

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sortedStatus = [false, false, false, false];
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  sortedStyler(columnNumber) {
    console.log("sortedStyler with", columnNumber);
    if (this.sortedStatus[columnNumber] == true) {
      //this.sortedStatus[columnNumber] = false;
    } else {
      this.sortedStatus[columnNumber] = true;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.sortedStatus.length; i++) {
        if (i != columnNumber) { this.sortedStatus[i] = false; }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

relevant **HTML**:

```html
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort class="mat-elevation-z8">
    
      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header (click)='sortedStyler(0)' [ngClass]="sortedStatus[0] === true ? 'boldArrow' : ''"> No. </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header (click)='sortedStyler(1)' [ngClass]="sortedStatus[1] === true ? 'boldArrow' : ''">  Name </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header (click)='sortedStyler(2)' [ngClass]="sortedStatus[2] === true ? 'boldArrow' : ''">  Weight </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header (click)='sortedStyler(3)' [ngClass]="sortedStatus[3] === true ? 'boldArrow' : ''">  Symbol </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
      </ng-container>
    
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
```

relevant **css**:

```css
    ::ng-deep .boldArrow .mat-sort-header-arrow.ng-trigger.ng-trigger-arrowPosition {
      opacity: 1 !important; 
    }
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-isxoc5-5u17zv?file=app/table-sorting-example.ts)